# Give UserA "write" access, but UserB is making commits

Tags: git, permissions, bitbucket

I have given UserA "write" permissions on my Git repo hosted on BitBucket using their email address.  But now I am seeing commits by UserB who has a different email address.

When I go to "User and group access" I only see UserA.

How can this be?  This has happened on two different occasions; I am hiring one person to work on my project, but they are sub-contracting out the work to someone else (which I do not want).

Comment: Slightly off topic, but since you brought it up: Does your contractor know you don't want them to subcontract the work? If yes, it's surprising that they would leave the commit authors of the other people intact before pushing the commits to your repo, unless they aren't very familiar with Git. That being said, if you complain, it will be very easy for them to hide that from you in the future and just lie to you about who did it. You should consider doing some soul searching and decide if you're happy with the work for the price you're paying, regardless of the commit author name.

Comment: You're right, I didn't specify no subcontracting (didn't realize I needed to). The point of hiring someone more senior is to give me less work (fewer comments in PRs, fewer headaches) and increased output. I find increasing my budget just increases the same developer's rates. Maybe my question should be: where can I hire senior remote developers for occasional work (other than freelancer dot com)

Comment: Maybe the following situation. There is really only one developer. But he commits from two different machines. On one machine, he uses the name UserA. On another machine - UserB. I have seen this on some projects. How significant are the differences in the name? It's probably the same person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume "write access" only applies to pushing. Committer and author information in commits is not checked. It is static information and trivial to fake (`git rebase --reset-author-date`). What would you gain? If you get their work done properly, does it really matter who did it? Does it matter if they had somebody else do it?

Don't rely on the information stored in commits. If you really must do this, then force them to GPG sign all of their commits and only allow signed commits. Verify the signature in a post-receive hook or pipeline. But even then, they could fake the author information and then sign the commit.

All such attempts are futile. Look, I just authored a commit as "Alan P.":

```
$ GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='Alan P.' GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='alanp@users.stackoverflow.com' git commit -m 'I honestly wrote this code all by myself!'
[master cca77e6] I honestly wrote this code all by myself!
 Author: Alan P <alanp@users.stackoverflow.com>
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 anyfile
$ git log -1
commit cca77e63c2ac4135e65ce0a35f60d05a50e362f8 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Alan P <alanp@users.stackoverflow.com>
Date:   Wed Oct 19 19:20:05 2022 +0200

    I honestly wrote this code all by myself!
```

Or even simpler:

```
$ git commit --author='Alan P. <alanp@users.stackoverflow.com>' -m 'Another commit that definitely nobody but me authored'
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. There seems to be a correlation between "getting the work done properly" and sub-contracting.  If I hire a senior dev at $50 per hour and they sub-contract out that work at $20 per hour, I've not been getting the code quality of a senior dev.

Comment: @AlanP. that sounds like a contractual or legal problem, not a technical problem. And if you don't get the quality which you (assumed you) paid for, discuss it with the dev. Nothing that Git can do here. Even if you somehow managed to restrict access to a single account, how would you prevent the dev from sharing his account password with another person?